# Automatic Disconnecting of Players and The game is kinda Lag in PUN 2

Tags: unity, photon

I am creating a 3d game application in unity with the use of PUN2. When I start the game, all players automatically disconnected and the animation of players is kinda lag or not synchronizing towards all players. I was wondering if it is because of the RPC's that i called.

I know this is kinda stupid but i have 200+ methods marked as PunRPC.

My Question is: does using or calling an RPC in PUN causes a lag and automatic disconnecting of player/s? or is it because i calls a lot of data/objects  all over the network?

I do have this error occurs when a player/s disconnected automatically:

**Error 1:**

> PhotonView ID duplicate found: 999. New: View 999 on RoomManager (scene) old: View 999 on RoomManager (scene). Maybe one wasn't destroyed on scene load?! Check for 'DontDestroyOnLoad'. Destroying old entry, adding new. UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object) Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:RegisterPhotonView(PhotonView) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:1003) Photon.Pun.PhotonView:Awake() (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonView.cs:590)

**Error 2:**

> InvalidOperationException: Duplicate key 999 ExitGames.Client.Photon.NonAllocDictionary`2[K,V].Add (K key, V val) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/DataTypes.cs:309) Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork.RegisterPhotonView (Photon.Pun.PhotonView netView) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:1014) Photon.Pun.PhotonView.Awake () (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonView.cs:590)

and I know this errors will occur only if I did not disconnected properly from the previous game on which my room manager still exist and did not destroy from the previous one...

Comment: Do you actually have that problem in your game? Can you give us more details about what exactly you are doing and about the exact nature of the problems you experience?

Comment: Hi @Philipp! I am creating a 3d game application in unity with the use of PUN2 and when I starts the game all players is automatically disconnected and the animation of players is kinda lag or not synchronizing towards all players.. and i was wondering if it is because of the RPC's that i called..

Comment: Can you provide more information on the RPC call?

Comment: I know this is kinda stupid but i have 200+  methods marked as PunRPC ... I am currently learning on photon unity networking hope you understand....

Comment: Having that amount of PunRPC may or may not cause your issues. It depends on how often you call them, how much traffic/ payload they have or if you have another error happening. Since you are learning Pun, is the game itself done and you try to add networking or are you creating the game and have reached already that amount of RPC methods?

Comment: Hi @Zibelas! Thanks for the response... i am creating the game and when the player/s automatically disconnected! this error occurs:

Comment: PhotonView ID duplicate found: 999. New: View 999 on RoomManager (scene) old: View 999 on RoomManager (scene). Maybe one wasn't destroyed on scene load?! Check for 'DontDestroyOnLoad'. Destroying old entry, adding new.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:RegisterPhotonView(PhotonView) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:1003)
Photon.Pun.PhotonView:Awake() (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonView.cs:590)

Comment: InvalidOperationException: Duplicate key 999
ExitGames.Client.Photon.NonAllocDictionary`2[K,V].Add (K key, V val) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/DataTypes.cs:309)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork.RegisterPhotonView (Photon.Pun.PhotonView netView) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:1014)
Photon.Pun.PhotonView.Awake () (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonView.cs:590)

Comment: Post those as edit to the question, not as a comment

Comment: and i know this error will occur if i did not disconnected it properly on which my room manager still exist and did not destroy from the previous one

Comment: But a quick google result: https://www.infogamerhub.com/fixing-duplicate-view-id-with-photon-2-in-unity/

Comment: You need to add that information to the question. We can only help you if you provide the information we need. Many people build working games with PUN, so when it does not work for you, then the most likely explanation is not that one of its most central features (RPC calls) just randomly lags out and disconnects players, but rather that you are using it in an incorrect way. What are you doing incorrectly? That's what *you* need to tell *us*.

Comment: Thanks! i'll edit my concern immediately...